# MySQL less than syntax

Tags: mysql

Can anyone see why this MySQL command should throw an error?

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE SUM(mycolumn) < 15.0;
```

Comment: Is the error like: `DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel.`

Comment: @Nerd-Herd An SQL fiddle error?

Comment: Yep! :) Had nothing else to do... @RicardoAltamirano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, `Sum` is an aggregate function, whereas `DELETE` operates on individual records.

Comment: Thanks. I needed HAVING and ORDER BY conditions in there.